# Flash AS3: How to parse regex found in parentheses in replacement string?

Tags: regex, flash, actionscript-3

I want to do something like this:

```
"3*4".replace(/([0-9]+)[*]([0-9]+)/g, String(Number("$1") * Number("$2")))
```

And no, i don't want to do that, but something more complex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
"3*4".replace(/(\d+)\*(\d+)/g, function():String {
  return String(Number(arguments[1]) * Number(arguments[2]));
});
```

Comment: According to the [docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/String.html#replace()) you can either pass a string or a function as the second param to replace. Here I use an anonymous function.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done in straight JavaScript like so:

```js
function process(text) {
    return text.replace(/(\d+)\*(\d+)/g, function(m0, m1, m2) {
            return m1.valueOf() * m2.valueOf();
        });
}
```